# Menu ativo após refresh com localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Tenho esse código que deixa o menu ativo e expande.

```
<li class="menu-item">
  <a href="#" class"active">
    <span>Posts</span>
  </a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Ver Posts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Novo Post</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>

$(".menu-item > a").click(function(){
  $(".sub-menu").slideUp();

  if(!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
    $(this).next().slideDown();
  } 

  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

  localStorage.setItem("activeDiv", $(this).index('.menu-item > a'));
 });

 var activeIndex = localStorage.getItem("activeDiv");
 if (activeIndex) {
   $('.menu-item').removeClass('active').eq(activeIndex).addClass('active'); 
 }
```

Como eu faço para quando eu clicar no submenu "Ver Posts ou Novo Post" ele
continuar aberto após o refresh da página?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na hora de "setar" o valor da key "**activeDiv**", o **$(this).index('.menu-item > a')** estava sempre passando **null**.

```
localStorage.setItem("activeDiv", $(this).index('.menu-item > a'));
```

Pra verificar qual valor a sua key está pegando, no Chrome, abra **Ferramentas do desenvolvedor** e vá na aba **Application**.

No exemplo a seguir eu utilizei os métodos **JSON.parse()** e **JSON.stringify()** pra contornar esse problema.

**[Documentação dos Métodos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)**

Adicionei uma verificação do localStorage dentro de **$(document).ready()**.

Caso seja **true**, faz **$('.sub-menu').show();**

Caso seja **false**, faz **$('.sub-menu').hide();**

**[Exemplo - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30mh3syx/1/)**

Comment: Funcionou! Porém tentei adicionar outros links e quando está true, todos ficam abertos.

Comment: Poderia mostrar um exemplo no JSFiddle? Fica mais fácil de visualizar o que está havendo. Pode usar o mesmo arquivo que eu passei de exemplo. Só editar, apertar **Update** e me passar o link

Comment: Não sei se resolve o seu caso, mas dá uma olhada no exemplo a seguir. 

Adicionei uma nova Key **activeDiv2** e fiz as verificações igual no exemplo anterior.

  https://jsfiddle.net/30mh3syx/5/

Comment: No menu tem Posts e Categorias, note que quando o true está setado ao atualizar a página os 2 ficam abertos e a classe active não permanece. https://jsfiddle.net/30mh3syx/6/

Comment: Isso ocorre porque a verificação 

`if (JSON.parse(activeIndex) == 'true') {
    $('.sub-menu').show();`

manda dar um **show()** em todo elemento com Class **sub-menu** quando **activeIndex** estiver **true**.

No exemplo a seguir eu contornei a situação criando novas classes, uma nova key e adicionando uma nova verificação: https://jsfiddle.net/30mh3syx/5/